# How to find which key triggered the form submit event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with multiple fields, But only have one required field. The issue is when the required field is filled and Enter key is pressed the form get submitted.

If Enter key is pressed inside a Text area there is no problem, But for Text box the form get submitted.

I was thinking the following as a solution.

- subscribe the podio form submit event.
- find which key caused the form submit
- if form submit is triggered by Enter key prevent the default action.

Right now i'm using the following method.

```
$("form").bind("keypress", function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {              
      e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

It is working fine. But is there a way that i can do this in form submit event?

Comment: disable the form.submit, and submit the form manually? when user click on button and post via ajax might be another work around

Comment: what you want, whether you want to avoid `TextBox - enter key` form submission, or identify the `key` if `TextBox - enter key` is pressed?

Comment: @NnN
I want know if enter key is causing the form submit inside form submit event.

Comment: form.onsubmit() listening to the form's submit event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After seeing your comment in previous answer, you could validate your form as like this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/58hvjpqj/4/)

**HTML:**

```
<table><form>
<tr>
    <td>First Name:
    </td>
    <td><input type='text' id='txtFName'/ >
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Last Name:
    </td>
    <td><input type='text' id='txtLName'/ >
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Age:
    </td>
    <td><input type='text' id='txtAge'/ >
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Email:
    </td>
    <td><input type='text' id='txtEmail'/ >
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" style='text-align:center;'><input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value=" Submit ">
    </td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
```

**JS:**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').submit(function(e) {
        var isValid = true;
        var allow = false;
        $('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
            if ($.trim($(this).val()) == '') {
                isValid = false;
                $(this).css({
                    "border": "1px solid red",
                    "background": "#FFCECE"
                });                 
            }
            else {
                $(this).css({
                    "border": "",
                    "background": ""
                });
            }
        });
        if (isValid == false){ 
            if(!confirm('Few Fields are empty! Are you sure want to continue?')){
                e.preventDefault();
          } else {
          alert('Thank you for submitting');
          }            
        }
        else 
           alert('Thank you for submitting');
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Old answer:**

```js
var Keys = {
  ENTER: 13
};

$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (checkIfAllRequiredFieldsAreFilled()) {
    $(this)[0].submit(); //call native event, since calling the jquery event will let you end up in the same function over and over again
  }
});

function checkIfAllRequiredFieldsAreFilled() {
  //do your checkings here, if they are complex. Otherwise just do them in the if-clause
  return true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

**If you just want to prevent and accidental submit, on pressing `enter`:**

```js
    var Keys = {
        ENTER: 13
    };

    $('form input').on('keypress', function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == Keys.ENTER) {
           event.preventDefault();
           console.log('Prevented Form-submit from: ', this);
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <label>
        Text: <input type="text"/>
    </label>
    <label>
        Number: <input type="number"/>
    </label>
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

---

[Don't use `.bind()`, use `.on()`:](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)

> As of jQuery 3.0, .bind() has been deprecated. It was superseded by
>   the .on() method for attaching event handlers to a document since
>   jQuery 1.7 [...]

Comment: The issue is, i only have one required field, all others are non mandatory.
So i can't confirm if client is filled all the field he/she want to fill.

Comment: @AkbarBadhusha well then just check if the one required `input` is filled (inside the `checkIfAllRequiredFieldsAreFilled()` function) and return the proper `true` or `false` and the code will do the rest. If `checkIfAllRequiredFieldsAreFilled()` returns `true` it **will** submit the formular.

Comment: I'm sorry if my requirement was not clear.

My issue is like this.

I have fields A,B,C and D
Only A is Mandatory.
Client filled A.
Then filled B and pressed enter accidentally. We can't be sure that if client is pressed the enter accidentally or he really wanted to submit the form.
So i desired to prevent the form submit on Enter press. 

Hope i made this time clear.